# Race condition and atomic operations in Julia and other languages

Tags: multithreading, julia, atomic

I have a several questions about atomic operations and multithreading.

1. There is a function for which a race condition occurs (julia lang):

```
function counter(n)
    counter = 0
    for i in 1:n
        counter += i
    end
    return counter
end
```

If atomic operations are used to change the global variable "counter", would that help get rid of the race condition?

2. Does protocol of cache coherence have any real effect to perfomance? Virtual machines like the JVM can use their own architectures to support parallel computing.
3. Do atomic arithmetic and similar operations require more or less resources than ordinary arithmetic?

It's difficult for me now. Hope for your help.

Comment: If atomic operations were faster, compilers would use them for everything.  Atomic RMWs are quite a bit more expensive, like even with no contention for the cache line from other cores, about 20x to 100x worse throughput on modern x86 CPUs than incrementing a register.  Plus being a full memory barrier, hurting out-of-order exec of loads/stores.  (related: [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) explains how CPUs handle them, including getting exclusive ownership of the containing cache line).

Comment: You must be in the same class as the asker of this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74684854/why-does-using-an-atomic-operation-still-allow-a-race-condition.  You should get together and help each other out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't quite understand your example, the variable `counter` seems to be local, and then there will be no race conditions in your example.

Anyway, yes, atomic operations will ensure that race conditions do not occur. There are 2 or 3 ways to do that.

**1.** Your counter can be an `Atomic{Int}`:

```
using .Threads
const counter = Atomic{Int}(0)
...
function updatecounter(i)
    atomic_add!(counter, i)
end
```

This is described in the manual: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/multi-threading/#Atomic-Operations

**2.** You can use a field in a struct declared as `@atomic`:

```
mutable struct Counter
    @atomic c::Int
end
const counter = Counter(0)
...
function updatecounter(i)
    @atomic counter.c += i
end
```

This is described here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/multi-threading/#Atomic-operations
It seems the details of the semantics haven't been written yet, but it's the same as in C++.

**3.** You can use a lock:

```
counter = 0
countlock = ReentrantLock()
...
function updatecounter(i)
    @lock countlock global counter += i
end
```

1. and 2. are more or less the same. The lock approach is slower, but can be used if several operations must be done serially. No matter how you do it, there will be a performance degradation relative to non-atomic arithmetic. The atomic primitives in 1. and 2. must do a memory fence to ensure the correct ordering, so cache coherence will matter, depending on the hardware.